# display validation errors using @html.validationmessagefor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I'm trying to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for displaying errors in MVC,
and I'm trying to do something like: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(@ViewBag.Price)` but I get syntax errors.
I want validation for this input:

`input type="number" value="@ViewBag.Price"  name="CurrentPrice"`

Comment: What is inside in `@ViewBag.Price`? How do you want to display a validation message for a viewbag value? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try writing `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.CurrentPrice)`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting syntax errors because `ValidationMessageFor` takes in a `Func`. You can't just use @ViewBag.Price in it and assume that it will work. The MSDN definition of that method [is right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

What you need to do is have that method be mapped to a specific field in your Model class (i.e. not the ViewBag) so that MVC knows precisely where to put the validation message should one come back after submission.

You could also instead just use `ValidationMessage`, which will take a field instead of a `Func`. A good example of using that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).